# Android Studio "No Connected Devices" HTC One (M7)

Tags: android, android-studio, htc-android

I know there are some questions like this but the solutions don't seem to work for me.

**What I tried/have already:**

- I enabled Developer Mode on the device
- I enabled USB Debugging and Fake Position in Developer Options on the device
- I can deploy a node cordova app with no problem
- There are no questionmarks in Device-Manager but Android-USB-Devices/My-HTC.
- The Google USB Driver is installed but HTC seems to be dependent on the driver that comes with the HTC Sync Manager. I installed/reinstalled/uninstalled it with no change. Currently I have no HTC Sync Manager but kept the HTC driver that came with it.
- I can see the device with cmd when I go to < android-sdk >\platform-tools and type `adb devices` and `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` doesn't change anything.
- I can even see the device when going to Tools>Android>Android-Device-Monitor in Android Studio as Online
- Run>Edit-Configuration>Target-Device is set to "USB device". If I set it to "Show chooser dialog" also nothing happens when pressing Run/Debug.
- I installed "Android 5.0.1 (API 21)" (I think that should be the right one) and other stuff with the Android SDK Manager. Only left out Android Wear and Samples on API 21.
- I have no build errors, it's a fresh blank App.
- I've always restarted Android Studio after everything I tried.
- I switched to the USB 2.0 port on my laptop (read somewhere that USB 3.0 can cause troubles)

I read that I should switch from MTP mode to PTP mode but I also read that HTC removed that with some update.

I have a HTC One (M7) with Android 5.0.2 (not hacked or anything) and Windows 8.1. Android Studio is current with v1.2.2. I usally don't develop for Android so it might be a very obvious thing.

[image: No connected devices]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still  don't know what the problem was but I upgraded to Windows 10, installed Visual Studio 2015 without the Android SDK and installed Android Studio. I opened a new Project with default settings and it worked. I didn't even install anything manually in the SDK Manager.[image: HTC One ADB works]

Answer (score 7):

I just wasted an hour with that problem with the same phone, but I finally made it, so here is what i did:

In `Developer options` the USB debugging was switched ON:

1. I disconnected the USB cable from the phone
2. The I disabled and re-enabled the USB debugging option
3. Then I clicked on `Revoke USB debugging authorisations` and confirmed with yes
4. Then I connected the USB cable to the phone and the popup that asks you to allow the connection finally showed up.
5. As soon as I confirmed it, Android Studio showed the the device...

That was it..
Hope it saves someone else's time.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the universal ADB drivers (https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver). Download  the installer from here: http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup.msi

Comment: I installed the *.msi package but with no change. It only asked again if I want to enable ADB. Anything else I should do besides installing it?

Comment: Yes, you need to activate the ADB in the developer options. Follow this instructions: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#Enabling

Comment: You mean the "USB Debugging" point in Developer Options right? I have that. "adb devices" command shows me my phone. Shouldn't I get some apk file when building the project? Searching for "*.apk" in the project folder gives no results that seems strange.

Comment: Yes, the problem should be on Android Studio. Did you tried to reinstall?

Comment: Reinstalling AS without reinstalling the sdk didn't help. I could format my pc, win10 comes out soon so good point in time.

Comment: Thanks for your help wiping the drive and installing everything again worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an HTC One (M7) with Android 5.0.2 but running on Windows 10. My current Android Studio is v1.4.1. This is what I did to resolve the "No Connected Devices" issue:

1. Uninstall any previous HTC drivers and software.
2. Download the HTC One device driver from this site: [Download HTC One Windows Drivers! [M7/M8]](http://androiddrivers.net/htc-android-drivers/download-htc-one-windows-drivers-m7m8/) - even though the site claims that the driver is meant for Windows XP, Vista, 7, and 8 (for 32-bit or 64-bit systems), it worked on my Windows 10 too!
3. Install the downloaded driver.

Now you can check on your Android Studio to see if your HTC device appears. It certainly worked on mine!

[image: Android Studio screenshot - HTC One (M7) detected]

Comment: Something in the screenshot seems to be different/weird, why "HTC HTC One", shouldn't have appeared twice. Device name?

Comment: @computingfreak, I would not think this to be a problem. The same observation can be seen from one of the answers with the screenshot below (answered by CodingYourLife).